# Correct way to manage showing multiple custom toolbars?

Tags: android

The structure of the app is one Activity and multiple Fragments(+ 20).

The Activity has a Toolbar with a title and back button that i used in multiple Fragments.

Then there is two more types of Toolbars that i use inside multiple Fragments, one contains an EditText and the other one is an Expandable Toolbar.

An example would be:

Fragment A: Uses Toolbar from Activity. Show that one, hide if another is showing.

Fragment B: Has a Toolbar of it own, now i need to hide the Activity toolbar.

What would be the correct approach to show/ hide the correct toolbar?

Things i tried:

- Using `onDestinationChangedListener` checking the id of the fragment and show/ hide the correct toolbar. The problem here is that it cause the screen to flicker and i have to check for every id.

  ```
  toolbar.isVisible = destination.id in listOf(id1, id2...)
  ```
- Hide or show the correct Toolbar from the Fragment. But then i need to set the toolbar on every Fragment.

  ```
  (requireActivity() as MainActivity).showToolbar(true)
  ```
- Removing the Activity Toolbar and creating a new one inside every Fragment. But i don't know if the best way and if it is expensive to constantly inflate the Toolbar.